# Cant resolve linker error using templates by not adding function to the header

Tags: c++, templates

I have this function defined in header:

```
template<typename T>
void GfxDevice::BindConstantBuffer(unsigned int stage, GfxConstantBuffer<T>* constantBuffer, unsigned int binding)
{
    GfxBufferResource* bufferResource = constantBuffer->GetBufferResource();
    if (!bufferResource->Initialized())
        bufferResource->Initialize();

    BindConstantBuffer(stage, bufferResource->GetBuffer(), binding);
}
```

I get linker error because compiler won't link Initialize() function that is defined in .cpp file. Is there any way of resolving that and that Initialize() stay in the cpp?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the reason, but I am wondering how to do this, because GfxBufferResource doesn't depend on T, so there must be a way, but having hard time keeping pretty and optimized code and not having linker errors, so wanted to see how are this problems resolved :)

Comment: Templates are really pain in the ass

Comment: This function is in ".hpp" file ( that is suggested by the link) , not exactly in header, but in the end it is the same thing, it will slow down compile time if I add bunch of libs there that are used in Initialize() function

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was just being stupid by frustration that template programming gave me :)

The solution is not that complicated i just needed to pass GfxBufferResource* in the BindConstantBuffer instead of doing that stuff in template function.

So solution:

```
    template<typename T>
void GfxDevice::BindConstantBuffer(unsigned int stage, GfxConstantBuffer<T>* constantBuffer, unsigned int binding)
{
    BindConstantBuffer(stage, constantBuffer->GetBufferResource(), binding);
}
```

and make BindConstantBuffer in GfxDevice that will receive GfxBufferResource and do it there.